# quiz timer in GUI Action Performed and Display in label

Tags: java

I want to create a quiz in which  user gets 1 min  for each question and the time left is displayed in label and which ever occurs first , i.e . question is answered or times up , automatically another question is displayed .. I have tried 
thread.sleep() but its not working and i  do not know how to use Timer class Please help me .  and if possible  I want that  when i press button i get countdown displayed from 60 to 1  in label